# PHP: Get value from array object mix

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap

I have a PHP SOAP-Client response (an array mixed with objects) from which I want to receive the value from the key **IDENT**. But whatever I do, I can't reach it. Does anyone have an idea how to access it?!

```
Array
(
    [0] => Cmp\ProdSoapStruct\Struct\Generic\HashMap Object
        (
            [items:Cmp\ProdSoapStruct\Struct\Generic\HashMap:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Cmp\ProdSoapStruct\Struct\Generic\HashMapItem Object
                        (
                            [key:Cmp\ProdSoapStruct\Struct\Generic\HashMapItem:private] => IDENT
                            [value:Cmp\ProdSoapStruct\Struct\Generic\HashMapItem:private] => 2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: Without knowing how those (looks like custom) classes works, we can't know how to access those private values. My guess would be that they have some getter functions?

Comment: you can use `is_object` and `is_array` to distinguish between these two, usually there is option to return only array or only object but dunno in your case, also there could be magic method defined for your objects like `__toArray` or they can extend `ArrayAccess` meta class so you can get values of it as it was an array